# How to render "Chance would be a fine thing" into French

Tags: expressions

In conversation, I wanted to express this idea in French:

> I asked him to try his best to be a good role model for her, but **chance would be a fine thing**.

In English, at least in England, this phrasing is used to say:

- There is only the slimmest, if any, chance that something you would love to see happen will actually come true.

I looked around and stumbled across some posts where some phrasings such as "*mais ça serait trop beau*" were suggested, but I don't find any of them satisfactory enough to be used in this context. I'd probably have said:

> Je lui avais pourtant dit de s’efforcer d’être un bon modèle pour elle, mais **c’était trop demander**.

How is this idea effectively expressed in French?

Answer (score 1):

When talking to people, in a casual manner, you can also express it like that:

> Je lui avais pourtant dit de s'efforcer d’être un bon modèle pour elle, **mais bon...** (l'intonation et le petit soufflement de dépit qui peuvent accompagner la fin de la phrase ne peuvent pas être aussi percutants à l'écrit qu'à l'oral).

Comment: Nice! An unexpected approach.

Answer (score 1):

Si vous voulez exprimer l'idée qu'il reste une petite chance que votre souhait soit exaucé, vous pouvez modifier légèrement votre proposition :

- Je lui avais pourtant dit de s’efforcer d’être un bon modèle pour elle, mais c’était *sans doute* trop demander.

Ce qui est proposé dans les deux réponses existantes convient très bien. Personnellement, j'utiliserais plutôt:

- Je lui ai dit de s’efforcer d’être un bon modèle pour elle, on peut toujours rêver ...

Answer (score 0):

I think the ironic use of *l'espoir fait vivre* might do the trick here :

- Je lui avais pourtant dit de s’efforcer d’être un bon modèle pour elle, l'espoir fait vivre.

Comment: Hi. What's your take on "*mais ça serait trop beau*" suggested by a native speaker?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens I've been thinking about this, my feeling is that "ça serait trop beau" implies that you've given up on the person trying to be a role model, whereas in English as you point out there is still a chance, albeit a slight one, that he could try to be role model. I might be overthinking this, though.