# How to say "have ideas above his station" in French?

Tags: expressions, anglais

In conversation, one of my colleagues said:

> He's thinking of making advances to the hospital director's daughter. If you ask me, he'**s got ideas above his station**. He's not set up for life or anything!

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in French. This expression means something like:

- *He's hoping for (/ He thinks he is qualified for) something unsuitable for someone of his social position*.

I'd probably have said:

> Il aimerait bien faire de la fille du directeur de l'hôpital sa dulcinée. Si tu veux mon avis, il **se pousse** un peu **du col**. Son avenir est loin d'être tout tracé !

I guess this is one of those expressions that do not translate easily into other languages. I wonder if my phrasing works? How is this idea commonly/idiomatically expressed in French?

Answer (score 2):

Il y a de très nombreuses manières d'exprimer cette idée, de la plus simple à la plus alambiquée ou drôle. Mais je garde toujours en tête que juger les pensées ou rêves des autres peut être extrêmement blessant et déplacé. Néanmoins, il y a plusieurs façons d'exprimer son étonnement ou sa désapprobation (ou approbation) :

1. Il rêve !
2. L'espoir fait vivre...
3. Il se voit trop beau / plus beau qu'il n'est...
4. Il a de l'espoir dans les chaussettes (très familier)
5. Il est a côté de la plaque (ou: de ses pompes - mais cela devient très familier)
6. Il va peut-être un peu vite en besogne (la plus "neutre" de mon point de vue, et, ici, dans le sens de "se précipite car il n'est pas prêt à affronter une telle situation" mais sans préjuger de sa capacité à réussir)
7. Il risque de s'y casser les dents.
8. Je ne sais pas s'il se rend compte de la situation.
9. Ils ne sont pas dans la même catégorie.
10. Il a les yeux plus grands que le ventre.
11. Il est loin du compte.

Bien sûr, l'expression s'adapte à l'interlocuteur :)

Comment: It's interesting how "l'espoir fait vivre" has been suggested in this post, too. :) https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37936/how-to-render-chance-would-be-a-fine-thing-into-french

Answer (score 1):

When I first read the sentence in English, I couldn't help translating *He's thinking of making advances to the hospital director's daughter* by *Il aimerait bien se faire la fille du directeur de l'hôpital*.  I hope you don't mind if I use that translation for my answer, which works better if the language is brought down a few notches from Dulcinea to a more earthy level:

- > Il aimerait bien se faire la fille du directeur de l'hôpital. Si tu veux mon avis, **il a pas le niveau**. Son avenir est loin d'être tout tracé !

Comment: That's not the language level found in the English; this language has nothing to do with the slangish expression of the uneducated.

Comment: @LPH  I know, that's what the little intro is about.  Thank you for stating the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> Il aimerait séduire la fille du directeur de l'hôpital. Si tu veux mon avis, il n'est pas à la hauteur. Il aurait fallu qu'ils fassent partie du même milieu social.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rather vulgar idiom that fits this situation where someone acts or tries to act as if they were in a superior social class but fail miserably to do so:

> Il pête plus haut que son cul.

Answer (score -1):

First, I wouldn't talk of ideas in this context, but of aspirations, ambitions, and the like.

"Il se pousse un peu du col." does not reflect this man's behaviour as corroborated to the apprehension we have of his station in life; that means that he simply pretends consciously to  have aptitudes he does not have, his aim being to impress people, nothing more; it's that simple.

> (TLFi)  il se pousse un peu du col : Se faire valoir; montrer un orgueil provocant :

The plain truth is that we don't know here whether he undervalues his relative worthiness in regard of that of the woman he wants to propose to. In the light of this most general context we can but come up with a statement of comparative evaluation; the following formulations serve that aim well, although there are others;

- Il aspire à plus qu'il ne peut prétendre.
- Il a des ambitions qui ne sont pas à la mesure de sa personnalité.
- Il a des ambitions qui vont au-delà de ce à quoi il peut prétendre.

The context can be specialised to that of *social* position; of course, the judgement  is somewhat on a different level;

- Il a des aspirations qui ne correspondent pas à sa position sociale.